# JWT: How do I implement my custom error message on password or username is wrong Django REST

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, jwt, django-rest-framework-jwt

I want to implement my own custome error message when user types wrong password in Django Rest JWT authentiction as of now default error message is

```
  "detail": "No active account found with the given credentials"
```

I have inherited Token Obtain  serializer as

```
class TokenPairSerializer(TokenObtainSerializer):
    default_error_messages = {
        'login_error': _('Username or Password does not matched .')
    }

    @classmethod
    def get_token(cls, user):
        return RefreshToken.for_user(user)

    @classmethod
    def get_user_type(cls, user):
        if user.is_superuser:
            return 'super_user'
        elif user.is_student:
            return 'student_user'
        elif user.is_teacher:
            return 'teacher_user'

    def validate(self, attrs):
        data = super().validate(attrs)
        self.validate_user()
        refresh = self.get_token(self.user)
```

I don't know where can I need to overrid  error message to get response as this

```
    'login_error': _('Username or Password does not matched .')
```

any help will be helpful.

Comment: Hi, Can you help me with this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72101444/how-to-customise-the-default-user-authentication-rule-in-django-rest-framework

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only need to change the default error message, override the **TokenObtainSerializer** **default_error_message** dictionary, and customize the **no_active_account** key.

Source code: [here](https://github.com/jazzband/djangorestframework-simplejwt/blob/b06723f1cbe1fc7fb77d161aed7de2c65581da14/rest_framework_simplejwt/serializers.py#L23)

to

```
class CustomTokenObtainSerializer(TokenObtainPairSerializer):
    default_error_messages = {
        'no_active_account': 'Username or Password does not matched.'
    }
```

Comment: @Apirmus How can I use this to get a different error message for is_active=False accounts?

Can you help me with this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72101444/how-to-customise-the-default-user-authentication-rule-in-django-rest-framework