# How to customize the in_active user error message for rest_framework_simplejwt in Django

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework-simplejwt

I have set my multiple user model in Django rest framework and I am using dj_rest_auth, allauth and djangosimplejwt for my user Authentication and Authorisation workflow

my serialisers.py look like this

```
class LoginSerializer(Serializer):
    email = EmailField(required=False, allow_blank=True)
    password = CharField(style={'input_type': 'password'})

    class Meta:
        model = Users
        fields = ['email', 'password']
        extra_kwargs = {
            'password': {'write_only': True},
            'style': {'input_type': 'password'},
        }

    def authenticate(self, **kwargs):
        return authenticate(self.context['request'], **kwargs)

    def _validate_email(self, email, password):
        if email and password:
            user = self.authenticate(email=email, password=password)
        else:
            msg = {'error': _('Did you forget to include an email or password?')}
            raise ValidationError(msg)

        return user

    def get_auth_user_using_allauth(self, email, password):
        from allauth.account import app_settings

        # Authentication through email
        if (
            app_settings.AUTHENTICATION_METHOD
            == app_settings.AuthenticationMethod.EMAIL
        ):
            return self._validate_email(email, password)

    def get_auth_user(self, email, password):
        """
        Retrieve the auth user from given POST payload by using
        either `allauth` auth scheme or bare Django auth scheme.

        Returns the authenticated user instance if credentials are correct,
        else `None` will be returned
        """
        if 'allauth' in settings.INSTALLED_APPS:

            # When `is_active` of a user is set to False, allauth tries to return template html
            # which does not exist. This is the solution for it. See issue #264.
            try:
                return self.get_auth_user_using_allauth(email, password)
            except url_exceptions.NoReverseMatch:
                msg = {'error': _('Unable to log in with provided credentials.')}

                # msg = 'Unable to log in with provided credentials.'
                raise exceptions.ValidationError(msg)
        return self.get_auth_user_using_orm(email, password)

    @staticmethod
    def validate_auth_user_status(user):
        if not user.is_active:
            msg = _('User account is disabled.')
            raise exceptions.ValidationError(msg)

    @staticmethod
    def validate_email_verification_status(user):
        from allauth.account import app_settings

        if (
            app_settings.EMAIL_VERIFICATION
            == app_settings.EmailVerificationMethod.MANDATORY
        ):
            email_address = user.emailaddress_set.get(email=user.email)
            if not email_address.verified:
                raise exceptions.ValidationError(
                    {'error': _('E-mail is not verified.')}
                )

    def validate(self, data):

        email = data.get('email')
        password = data.get('password')
        user = self.get_auth_user(email, password)

        if not user:
            msg = {'error': _('Unable to log in with provided credentials.')}
            raise exceptions.ValidationError(msg)

        # Did we get back an active user?
        self.validate_auth_user_status(user)

        # If required, is the email verified?
        if 'dj_rest_auth.registration' in settings.INSTALLED_APPS:
            self.validate_email_verification_status(user)

        data['user'] = user
        return data
```

and my views.py looks like this

```
class Login(LoginView):
    """
    Check the credentials and return the REST Token
    if the credentials are valid and authenticated.
    Calls Django Auth login method to register User ID
    in Django session framework

    Accept the following POST parameters: username, password
    Return the REST Framework Token Object's key.
    """

    serializer_class = LoginSerializer

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        self.request = request
        self.serializer = self.get_serializer(data=self.request.data)
        self.serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)

        self.login()
        return self.get_response()

    def get_all_clients(self):
        """
        Using related objects, get all clients of the business
        """
        business = self.request.user
        business_client = ClientProfile.objects.filter(business=business)

        client_list = business_client.values(
            'client__id',
            'client__email',
            'client__fullname',
            'logo',
        )

        # rename the keys in clean_names
        for client in client_list:
            client['id'] = client.pop('client__id')
            client['email'] = client.pop('client__email')
            client['fullname'] = client.pop('client__fullname')
            client['logo'] = (
                f"{self.request.META['HTTP_HOST']}{business.profile_image.url}"
                if client['logo']
                else None
            )

        return client_list

    # display user profile information based on type of user
    def get_response(self):
        response = super().get_response()
        user = self.request.user

        if user.type.name == "Business":

            profile = {
                'profile': {
                    'business_logo': f"{self.request.META['HTTP_HOST']}{user.businessprofile.logo.url}"
                    if user.businessprofile.logo
                    else None,
                    'business_name': user.businessprofile.business_name,
                    'user_type': user.type.name,
                    'client_list': self.get_all_clients(),
                }
            }
            response.data.update(profile)
            return response

        elif user.type.name == 'Client':

            profile = {
                'profile': {
                    'logo': (
                        f"{self.request.META['HTTP_HOST']}{user.clientprofile.logo.url}"
                    )
                    if user.clientprofile.logo
                    else None,
                    'name': user.clientprofile.client_business_name,
                    'type': user.type.name,
                    'full_name': user.fullname,
                    'country': user.country.name,
                }
            }
            response.data.update(profile)

        return response
```

first thing I notice is when a user has an inactive account i.e user.is_active I want to write a more meaningful message to make it easy for the frontend but when I use the browsable api I get

```
{
  "error": [
    "Unable to log in with provided credentials."
  ]
}
```

and when I use postman I get a 401 error dictionary

```
{
  "detail": "User is inactive",
  "code": "user_inactive"
}
```

the above error comes when I use the [dj_rest_auth documentation](https://dj-rest-auth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html) that says I should add

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
        'dj_rest_auth.jwt_auth.JWTCookieAuthentication',
    ),
    
}
```

But if I follow [Django simplejwt documentation](https://django-rest-framework-simplejwt.readthedocs.io/en/latest/getting_started.html) it says

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework_simplejwt.authentication.JWTAuthentication',
       )
}
```

I only get this both on postman and browsable api endpoint

```
{
  "error": [
    "Unable to log in with provided credentials."
  ]
}
```

I will appreciate if I can get a valid way to get the proper error message that I want and a little explanation on why there are different error codes and documentation for using this

Comment: I you are using a custom login view then you can make your own checks and generate the refresh and access tokens manually. They will function same way as they do in the default case

Comment: where do I add this 
```
   @staticmethod
    def validate_auth_user_status(user):
        if not user.is_active:
            msg = _('User account is disabled.')
            raise exceptions.ValidationError(msg)
```
does not seem to get called in the serialiser please any suggestion

Comment: please can you tell me how to go about this ??

Comment: It seems you are using multiple user models and I have never worked with them. But I think you shoul work with one user models and have different different profile models for them. Then you can manually validate all the creds with if else statements and return tokens which you can also generate manually (the doc shows how), and send them as response